# How can I fix the ssl_certification error, which is generated by ssl package and using in the restAPIs

Tags: python-3.x

I am downloading the SSL certificate from the vCenter 6.5 and copying the certificate in a file like below.

```
cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((server, port))

with open(file_name, "w") as outfile:
   outfile.write(cert)
```

later when I am using the file_name in the restAPI's , getting the error 
`[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:618)`

I tried to cross verify the certificate in the Shell but got the below error

```
# openssl verify -verbose -CAfile file_name file_name 
file_name: CN = pn-a26-ub-15-7-vc.cisco.com, C = US
error 20 at 0 depth lookup:unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Can someone help on what went wrong on generating the certificate

Answer (score 0):

The file you pass via `-CAfile` parameter should contain the root (and intermediate, if there is one) certificates used to issue the certificate to be verified. You seem to be passing the server certificate itself.

If this is a CA-signed certificate you can omit the `-CAfile` argument. If not, you should supply the issuer chain in PEM format. As far as I remember vCenter uses self-signed certificates. You may be able to download the root certificates using the method described [here](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2108294).

Comment: Actual issue is not with "openssl verify ...". I used this to cross verify the whether the certificate is corrupted or not. Main issue here is, not able to use the downloaded the certificate in the restAPI. I downloaded with "ssl.get_server_certificate" and when I use in the certificate in the restAPI, getting  the error "CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]"

Comment: The server certificate is not used to verify itself; you must download the CA certificate using the link I provided and add it to the operating system trust store or some place that your rest client specifies. How do you make the rest API call?

Comment: Yes Selcuk, we should download the CA certificate by using link and use that for further processing. Thanks for the inputs.